# How to import fonts in Unity at Runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fonts, runtime, deserialization

I'm creating a Visual Novel in Unity and i'd like to give the player the option to import his own fonts into the game, my initial idea was to explain to the player that he needs to put the font file in a specific folder and i would scan the fonts in that folder using `System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles();`, though i do manage to access those files, i still haven't figured out how to deserialize those font files(.ttf) into Unity's Font type. The binary formatter throws a exception when trying to serialize/deserialize Unity's Font Type and as far as i searched Unity does not have a native API to do that, Unity imports fonts using the class TrueTypeFontImporter that's only implemented in the Editor, so i cannot access that class at runtime.

Anybody got any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: that's a great question! I have a bad feeling it is platform dependent ..

Comment: The only platform i would install this "feature" on would be Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be too late, but for late-comers.
You can load dynamic .ttf file by

```
Font font = new Font ("path_to_ttf_file");
```

As for static .ttf file, I dont know.

Comment: Although this might work, we switched to Text Mesh Pro sometime ago which uses it's own different font objects.